# error on django application in heroku when debug is set to False

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

Please I wanted to test my django application on heroku with the team before buying the host, but I get server error(500) when I set debug=False and try to access the login page or signup page, I have gone through the code but not finding any issue, but when I set the debug=True, the login and signup pages open fine.

Also, when I upload an image, it displays for a while, when I revisit the page, the image will disappear, please help.

this is my setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for EtufuorFarm project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

import datetime
import os
from pathlib import Path
import dj_database_url
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'django-insecure-qut(+bhgj@au6z4tl!_z8c(k%yes@)f(8x4lb%l6knh7n$d')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['etufuormarket.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #'admin_material.apps.AdminMaterialDashboardConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'farmapp.apps.FarmappConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_filters',
    'crispy_bootstrap5',
    #'social_django',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
   # 'rest_framework_jwt',
]
CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # Third Part Middleware
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'EtufuorFarm.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'EtufuorFarm.wsgi.application'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
#     }
# }
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
    ),
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'farmapp.CustomUser'

TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Accra'


LOGIN_URL = '/login'

#LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: For your second question check https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted-from-the-application also don't ask multiple questions in the same post.

Comment: Okay thanks but what of the first question, any idea??

Comment: Its hard to tell, my guess would be improper static file configuration, you might want to follow the MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment, it might help